# From a list of html elements with a common attribute to an array of their values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given HTML such

```
<span class="L5" letters="a"></span>
<span class="L5" letters="b"></span>
<span class="L5" letters="c"></span>
<span class="L5" letters="d"></span>
<span class="L5" letters="e"></span>
```

How to return an array :
var list = [ 'a','b','c','d','e' ];

I tried `$(".L5").attr("letters");` [without success (jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/77c4bbcq/1/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the array of elements with that class type then push their attribute letters value into a new array.

```
let list= [];
let spanElements = $('.L5');

for(let x =0; x < spanElements.length; x++){
    list.push($(spanElements[x]).attr('letters'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ryan's answer will definitely do the job with jQuery.  However, and I'm not sure how many elements you are going to be parsing in this way, if performance matters you can accomplish the same thing without jQuery by using `Array.from()` and `map()`

```
var list = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('L5')).map(function (element) {
    return element.attributes.letters.nodeValue
});
```

[Fiddle with console.time()](https://jsfiddle.net/JMM75/smmmo2uz/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) combined with [jQuery.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Code:

```js
const list = $('.L5').map((index, elem) => $(elem).attr('letters')).get();

console.log(list);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="L5" letters="a"></span>
<span class="L5" letters="b"></span>
<span class="L5" letters="c"></span>
<span class="L5" letters="d"></span>
<span class="L5" letters="e"></span>
```